# Ubuntu server internal specifications

Tags: server, kernel

i'm doing a homework assignment for my college, and I'm trying to find the parameters used in kernel compilation on RedHat.

My teacher asks: "Analyse and describes in terms of models of each version of linux for Servers: process, scheduling, memory management, file system, security"

I searched in all the internet, someone will say that every kernel is the same, but have some parameters that each distro can modifie and change the hole thing, is what i'm searching for.

Can someone answer me where can i find these informations?

Answer (score 1):

You find this information in the source package of the kernels by examining any patches applied to the kernel source and configuration options found in the kernel .config

Comment: i found the parameters used on compilation, but where can i find what it means?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/ or textbook http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c4029/code/memory/understanding.pdf